# How to transform palantir foundry struct values to columns and its value

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-contour

input column values in below format

```
{ "actualDuration": null, "actualCloseDate": 1.25, "actualDoneDate": null }
```

output expected

```
column name-actualDuration   column name- actualCloseDate  column name-actualDoneDate
               null                       1.25                           null
```

is there any function like `split` or `explode`?

Comment: Hi @mohan-rao and welcome to stackoverflow. I have edited your question to make it easier to follow. Could you add some more detail in the question of where you are trying to do this? Is it in `foundry-contour` exclusively like the tag indicates?